# Unity2D: Camera causes weird tearing issues when the end of the camera view is at x=0 or y=0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a weird tearing issue i have been trying to fix without success.
It turns out that if the end of one side of the camera view from my camera reaches x = 0 of WorldSpace (or y = 0) it causes some tearing in my Game.

At first i thought it might be the canvas because of the Positioning of it but im very certain thats not the case because turning off the canvas or removing it completely and restarting Unity doesn't fix the issue at all.

Here are some screenshots. The Tearing can only be seen in Game Mode.

[Game not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09zQ9.png)

[Game running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuVM0.png)

Comment: Probably your problem is z direction of camera and rendered objects. When changing camera position from script don't change z if you really don't have to. (You are making 2d game probably no need to). And ensure objects that should be rendered have greater **z** value than camera. Default objects have 0 **z** and camera has **-10 z** value.

Comment: I don't now where the -6 of Z came from (i probably tested something idk) but even a z-coordinate of -1 doesn't fix the problem. As you can see in the first picture, the issue is still there even without the game running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found an answer.

I just set ''Detect Chunk Culling Bounds" to Manual and put it to x=1 and y=1.